# How to change Server API from CGI/FastCGI to apache2handler

Tags: php, apache, cgi, fastcgi

I do not know that how can i change the server API.
When i run my `phpinfo();`. t shows me the Server API is 'CGI/FastCGI'.

I want to change it. can any one help me to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I also am looking for this but as far i know it is not possible without recompiling apache and php.

Answer (score 0):

To change Server Api FPM to apache2handler, As far you know yo need to compile PHP. Apache compile does not necessary. In fact if you are using Apache Passanger mod or else, compiling Apache might bring problems.
So that is why you do not want to compile Apache to change Server Api for PHP.

To compile PHP as Apache mod you could see this manual;
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php
Skip to compiling PHP part.
Download and extract PHP and open the directory on terminal (if you are running with a GUI on your server).
write this to your terminal `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-curl`
If you do not want curl support you can remove it.
You may have some problems during this period one them might libxml2 error just `apt-get install libxml2` or `yum instal libxml2`.
Another one might be related with curl. You could get an error saying that "curl could not found on it's default location" so if you get this error here is the solution `apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` after that start `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-curl` later  `make` and finally `make install` you should have look at the manual that i have given for further instructions if you need.